# javascript multidimensional associative array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

So I have

```
var arrays = [
    [ Material A, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5  ],
    [ Material B, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10  ],
    [ Material C, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15  ]
];
```

and I need to put it in this format which is a multidimensional associative array,

```
var bigdata = [
    { "Name": "MaterialA", "Row1": 1, "Row2": 2, "Row3": 3, "Row4": 4, "Row5": 5 },
    { "Name": "MaterialB", "Row1": 6, "Row2": 7, "Row3": 8, "Row4": 9, "Row5": 10 },
    { "Name": "MaterialC", "Row1": 11, "Row2": 12, "Row3": 13, "Row4": 14, "Row5": 15 }
];
```

I am trying

```
var bigdata = new Array(3);         

for (i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    // do name
    bigdata[i][0] = {"Name" : arrays[i][0]};

    for (j=1; j<6; j++ )
    {
        // rest of that row         
    }
}
```

But so far it is not working when I try to store the first "Name": "MaterialA" . What am I doing wrong or can this even be done? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't see commas separating the inner-most arrays in the arrays var. And why have single element arrays?

Comment: Is this exact syntax for your array definition? I mean, you have three level array the way you've declared it.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles yes sorry about that, I forgot the commas, I will fix that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to set a property of an associative array/object is like this:

```
bigdata[i]["Property"] = value   // this allows dynamic property name
bigdata[i].Property = value      // or like this, if property is hard-coded
```

So in your case, it should be:

```
bigdata[i] = {}   // initialize a blank object
bigdata[i].Name = arrays[i][0];

for ( j=1; j<6; j++ )
    bigdata[i]["Row" + j] = arrays[i][j];
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/56tk5/

Comment: Thanks that definitely helped. However when I try to access the first spot in bigdata, I use bigdata[0] and it returns [object Object]. I thought it would say "Name": "MaterialA". Am I accessing that incorrectly?

Comment: If you want to reference a specific value, use the same code - `bigdata[i].Name`.  If you are trying to output the contents in a readable way, you can use something like `JSON.stringify`.  The `bigdata` object has the equivalent contents as the example you provided in your post - it just doesn't display that way if you directly dump it out.

Comment: The `bigdata` example in the question is an array, not an object.

Comment: The object `bigdata` is an array, however each entry in the array `bigdata[i]` is an object.

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me. Notice I removed the `[0]` from your `bigdata[i][0]`, and added the row assignment code to your "j" loop.

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    // do name
    bigdata[i] = {"Name" : arrays[i][0]};

    for (j=1; j<6; j++ )
    {
        // rest of that row
        bigdata[i]['Row' + j] = arrays[i][j];
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ub54S/1/

Comment: Yes thank you. Also you were right earlier about the single element arrays. I thought they were single element arrays but are instead separated by commas. I fixed it in the original post to reflect the suggestion.

Comment: I updated my response. Also, in your example, the "Material A/B/C" array elements are not quoted. I assume that's a typo in your post too.

Comment: Actually they are unquoted in arrays but then when they get put into bigdata they need to have quotes surrounding them.